# VS2022 nis not compiling typescript files to js files

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio, precompile

I have a large VS2022 asp.net website ap. When it compiles, the ts files do not compile to js files. This is a new situation (I haven't played with this ap in about a year.
I have repaired vs2022 and installed the latest typescript build NuGet assembly.
Not sure where to look next.
Any suggestions?
Thanks
Abbott